# Ionic4/Cordova - The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devises associated with it

Tags: cordova, ionic4

I am using Ionic4 and I want to use the native Ionic HTTP package due to cors issues. In order to do that, I have to install the cordova plugin:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http
```

Which is asking to have Cordova up and running, so I:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Then I try again to install the plugin and next error appears

The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devises associated with it.

I also try to look the service in my windows services list but could find it, how can I start it manually?

Note that I have already tried  npm uninstall -g cordova

Full error:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http --save
\Users\Ezequiel\Desktop\galum\front\testFirebase\node_modules\windows-release\
de_modules\execa\index.js:347
              throw err;
              ^

ror: Command failed: wmic os get Caption
scription = The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or be
use it has no enabled devices associated with it.

  at makeError (c:\Users\Ezequiel\Desktop\galum\front\testFirebase\node_module
windows-release\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
  at Function.module.exports.sync (c:\Users\Ezequiel\Desktop\galum\front\testF
ebase\node_modules\windows-release\node_modules\execa\index.js:338:15)
  at windowsRelease (c:\Users\Ezequiel\Desktop\galum\front\testFirebase\node_m
ules\windows-release\index.js:34:24)
  at osName (c:\Users\Ezequiel\Desktop\galum\front\testFirebase\node_modules\o
name\index.js:39:18)
  at new Insight (c:\Users\Ezequiel\Desktop\galum\front\testFirebase\node_modu
s\insight\lib\index.js:37:13)
  at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Ezequiel\Desktop\galum\front\testFirebase\no
_modules\cordova\src\telemetry.js:26:15)
  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
  at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
RROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

      cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http --save exited with exit

      code 1.

      Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more
      information.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the version of Cordova to install:

```
npm install -g cordova@8.0.0
```

Comment: Is this an answer?